# Fantasy movie with a deaf man, strong man who hurls cannon balls and a flying ship

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can't remember a fantasy movie I watched when I was young, but I can recall a group of strange persons. One is deaf who uses a cone to enhance his hearing. And another is a strong man who hurls cannon balls. And there is a flying ship. It may be a 90s or 80s movie.

Answer (score 34):

Took me forever to find an image of the guy with the ear horn... but pretty sure this is *[The Adventures of Baron Munchausen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Baron_Munchausen)*, from 1988.

[image: picture of a man with white hair and a white mustache, holding an ear horn up against his ear]

The titular baron is a teller of tale tales, and in his stories has a travelling group that includes some pretty strange but talented friends, among them Eric Idle.  He is actually telling his tales to a theater putting on a play, while the city outside is under siege.

Comment: And the cannonballs?

Comment: @Valorum - Uhhhh... Dunno really.  Idle's character had the ball and chain, and cannonball riding was in there.  Not finding a perfect fit there.  But I really need to watch the movie again.

Comment: @Valorum, like Radhil said, the Baron rides on cannonballs.  And another of his companions is a very strong man, who are one point throws a wrecked ship though the air, which is I suspect the OPs reason for thinking of flying ships.  This movie was my first thought, too.

Comment: This link could help the op define if this is the movie he is referring to: https://dangerousminds.net/comments/off_with_your_nose_a_look_at_the_long_strange_cinematic_history_of_baron_mu

Comment: After the climactic battle, the jubilant Albrecht (Winston Dennis) picks up a very large cannonball on the beach and tosses it straight up in the air. A couple of seconds later he catches it, loses his balance and falls laughing to the sand.

Comment: Amazing. Maybe this is it. I'll look it up. Thanks a lot ;)